# What is the simplest way to convert a Java string from all caps (words separated by underscores) to lower (replacing _ by .)?

Tags: java

The title pretty much says it all. What's the simplest/most elegant way that I can convert, in Java, a string from the format "THIS_IS_AN_EXAMPLE_STRING" to the format "this.is.an.example.string"? I figure there must be at least one way to do it using String.replaceAll() and a regex.

My initial thoughts are: convert the whole string to lower case, and then use replaceAll to convert _ to .

Comment: `String modified = original.toLowerCase().replace("_", ".");`

Comment: Your initial thought is right. Why don't try it out? Don't hesitate to give it a try when you have a thought. Go ahead to write the code and ask for help when you encounter error. That's how people learn to code. Don't give up and ask right away before trying.

Answer (score 1):

str.toLowerCase().replaceAll("_",".");